# Disable number entry in input type='text' in mobile keyboard

Tags: mobile, input, keyboard

I am developing one hybrid mobile application for both Android and iOS. For some form I do not want to allow user to type number:

```
<input type='text'>
```

I tried with `event.keyCode`, `event.which`, `event.key` as they works in desktop browser, But in mobile keyboard it's not working.

Please remember I don't want to validate on submit or on click. I just want to disable the number keys. Is there any way?

Comment: Please share the event listener code you're using.

Comment: @Mottie Thanks for showing interest in my query. I used with kyeup,keypress,keydown.

Comment: You'll need to include touch events... I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/pnc2y0u2/)):

```js
function checkKey(e) {
  if (/\d/.test(e.key)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  } 
}

const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('touchstart', checkKey);
input.addEventListener('keydown', checkKey);
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Not working in mobile browser!